# Proving mutual orthogonality of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let three vectors $\mathbf{a}$, $\mathbf{b}$ and $\mathbf{c}$ in three-space be such that:

$$ a_ia_j + b_ib_j + c_ic_j = \delta_{ij} $$

where a vector name with subscript represents a component of the vector (the subscript can take the value 1,2 or 3) and $ \delta_{ij} $ is the Kronecker delta.

Is it true that $\mathbf{a}$, $\mathbf{b}$ and $\mathbf{c}$ are therefore mutually orthogonal?

Comment: Take $e_1,e_2,e_3$.

Comment: Yes since the rows of the matrix M=(a, b, c) are orthonormal, which means that M is an orthogonal matrix. So M's columns are also orthonormal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $P$ is the square matrix with one vector in each column, you are saying $P P^T = I.$ What do you think you get for $P^T P?$

Comment: I never thought about the question in this light! I did not realise it was in fact so simple. Thank you very much for this elegant answer.